# Can I install mongodb on mac M1 without rosetta?

Tags: database, mongodb, apple-m1

When I install it I get a very rare error:

```
 zsh: bad CPU type in executable
```

which makes me think that there is something wrong at low level

But it would help me a lot if you share your experiences with me

Comment: If you are simply looking for a viable local MongoDB, you may consider [MongoDB docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) as an alternative.

Comment: There are lots of ways to run mongodb on an M1 ... can you provide some more info as to what version of Mongo and MacOS and how you are trying to install it?  What command, specifically, fails?